# KDevelop 4.3.1 not parsing Eigen 3

Tags: parsing, eigen, kdevelop

I'm using KDevelop 4.3.1 on ubuntu 12.04. It's not parsing the Eigen 3 library, while this [release note](http://kdevelop.org/kdevelop/kdevelop-431-released-improved-gcc-47-compliance) says it should.

It is a little more subtle than this.

KDevelop is parsing part of the Eigen library when placing a `using namespace Eigen` before the code. However, it will not parse into the the classes (e.g. Identity in `Matrix2d::Identity()` will not be parsed).

When using nested namespaces, it will parse the namespace, but nothing more (e.g. Matrix2d in `Eigen::Matrix2d` will not be parsed), except for something called `internal` (i.e. `Eigen::internal`).

I've only found this [post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.kde.users.kdevelop/5659) which resembled my problem, although here the issue is resolved after a KDevelop crash. Does anyone have a more reliable sollution? Is there anyone with the same issue, at all?

Kind regards

PS: Building the code works fine.